# Separate pages for items in MEAN application

Tags: node.js, angularjs, express, coffeescript, mongoose

I'm writing application with Node, Express, Mongoose and Angular. I can display all items on a page. My next step is to write separate page for items from database, so i create route:

```
app.get '/products/:product_id', (req, res) ->
    Product.findById req.params.product_id,  (err, product) ->
        res.send(err) if (err)
        res.render('product.html', { name: product.name } )     
        return      
    return
```

Everything cool, i can display name with <%= name %> in product.html, but Angular doesn't work. Without '/:product_id' work. 
This is my route to get all products:

```
app.get '/api/products', (req, res) ->
    Product.find (err, products) ->
       if (err)
            res.send(err)
        res.json(products); # return all products in JSON format
        return
    return
```

And on the front side:

```
$http.get('/api/products')
    .success (data) ->
        $scope.products = data
        console.log(data)
        return
    .error (data) ->
        console.log('Error: ' + data)
        return
```

So, how i can write application, in which i go to http://mydomain.com/products/53c68728c7e5a5381a000002 then one item will display? (53c68728c7e5a5381a000002 is id)

Comment: I am rather new to the MEAN way of things, but just thinking logically, if Angular is doing an HTTP GET on your route and it is technically returning a render html, wouldn't that mess it up?

For example:
You are rendering the page already with the data. With angular, you are making a request to the route after the page has been rendered to the same route which returns html. You should probably set up your products/:product_id similar to your api/products, and then when you render angular, have it request the api/products/:product_id.

Comment: But how send to angular id? When I type www.domain.com/products/643284, how angular will know, that id is 643284?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you're not sending the id on the angular side.

In that case, you should create a $resource service :

```
myApp.factory('ProductService', [ '$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('http://mydomain.com/products/:id', {
        id : '@_id'
        });
} ]);
```

And then call it in your controller :

```
myApp.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'ProductService', '$routeParams',
    function($scope, ProductService, $routeParams) {

    $scope.findOne = function() {
        $scope.product = ProductService.get({
            id : $routeParams.id
        });
    };
} ]);
```

It will only work if you include your service in the controller declaration (aswell as routeParams if it's not there already), and if you have your routes set up correctly on the front-end side :

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/product/:id', {templateUrl: 'partials/product.html', controller: 'MyCtrl'});
}]);
```

Comment: The only thing I would think is an issue is once the request is made to /products/:product_id, it will return the html. I would either change  the server products/:product_id request to return the JSON data or change the clientside resource url to /api/products/:id. Outside of that, that is what I was thinking.

Comment: You're right, I would definitely recommend sending only the JSON data to AngularJS.

Comment: Maybe i'm stupid, but can't call $resource service in my controller, this:
 app.controller 'StoreController', ['$scope', 'ProductService', '$routeParams', ($scope, ProductService, $routeParams) ->
and this
app.controller 'StoreController', ($scope, ProductService, $http) ->
don't work for me. Last thing, myApp.config, must also be in file with controller (front-side)?

Comment: You should take a look at the angular seed project https://github.com/angular/angular-seed to get a better idea of the structure i'm using. You can also use boilerplate apps for the MEAN stack (see mean.js or mean.io), they provide you with a basic CRUD, which is what you seem to be doing.

Comment: It is important to add angular-route.min.js. Is it very bad, that i used angular-route in version 1.2.0 and others in 1.1.5?

Comment: One more question, this: $routeProvider.when('/view1', {templateUrl: 'views/product.html', controller: 'MyCtrl1'}); works like route on server side? I mean, with this, on mydomain.com/view1 will render product.html, or i must do something else?

Comment: Yes, that's the idea behind route. And yes, you need to add angular-route.js (or the minified version), else it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Still doesn't work.
Routes (backend):

```
app.get '/products/:product_id', (req, res) ->
    Product.findById req.params.product_id,  (err, product) ->
        res.send(err) if (err)
        res.render('product.html', { name: product.name } )     
        return      
    return
```

App.js (Front):

```
config(['$routeProvider', ($routeProvider) ->
   $routeProvider.when('/products/:id', {templateUrl: 'views/product.html', controller: 'StoreControllerOne'});
```

Controllers.js (Front):

```
.controller 'StoreControllerOne', ['$scope', '$http', 'ProductService', '$routeParams', 
($scope, $http, ProductService, $routeParams) ->

$scope.findOne = ->
    $scope.product = ProductService.get({
        id : $routeParams.id
    });
    console.log($scope.product.id)
    return
]
```

Services.js (Front):

```
.factory('ProductService', [ '$resource', ($resource) ->
    return $resource('/products/:id', {
        id : '@_id'
       });
 ]);
```

When i go to www.mydomain.com/products/53c92d5dda9cef6c23000002, JS console said, that can't find www.mydomain.com/products/javascripts/app.js for example, bu this file is in  www.mydomain.com/javascripts/app.js. Because adding ../ in html file is not good practice and it not work with directives.

Comment: Did you ever fix this?

Comment: Are you using your own MEAN stack or one of the libraries already out there?

Comment: I started this tutorial http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/creating-a-single-page-todo-app-with-node-and-angular and one from codeschool (AngularJS). I'm developing this project.

Answer (score 0):

I had to do some reserach to make sure I am not wrong because I don't have a lot of experience with  MEAN. However, looking at meanjs and their implementation, it seems to remain the same.

According to the sample articles routes.js https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/app/routes/articles.server.routes.js

```
app.route('/articles/:articleId')
    .get(articles.read)    //<----THIS GUY RIGHT HERE
    .put(users.requiresLogin, articles.hasAuthorization, articles.update)
    .delete(users.requiresLogin, articles.hasAuthorization, articles.delete);
```

They do a call to articles.read. So we find that function in the controller section.
https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/app/controllers/articles.server.controller.js

This function grabs and returns the req.article

```
exports.read = function(req, res) {
    res.jsonp(req.article);
};
```

Which if you dig deeper is found using mongoose and added to the req.

```
exports.articleByID = function(req, res, next, id) {
    Article.findById(id).populate('user', 'displayName').exec(function(err, article) {
        if (err) return next(err);
        if (!article) return next(new Error('Failed to load article ' + id));
        req.article = article;
        next();
    });
};
```

and in the articles angular controller
https://github.com/meanjs/mean/blob/master/public/dist/application.js

```
 $scope.findOne = function () {
      $scope.article = Articles.get({ articleId: $stateParams.articleId });
    };
```

You are still returning HTML as part of the request. Let angular handle the routing and pull the data from a request to your node server.

```
app.get '/products/:product_id', (req, res) ->
    Product.findById req.params.product_id,  (err, product) ->
        res.send(err) if (err)
        res.json({ name: product.name })     
        return      
    return
```

Or something to that effect. When your resource or even a simple http request is made to `/products/:product_id` then whatever you are returning via the res is what it tries to parse. If you are doing res.render it is going to return that as a response and break because you are expecting something else.

**EDIT** In reference to the comment on what tutorial you are using *

**Add to Server Side** - This will add an api route to return JSON data for that product/product_id

```
//View a product
    app.get('/api/products/:product_id', function(req, res) {
        Product.findOne({
            _id : req.params.product_id
        }, function(err, product) {
            if (err)
                res.send(err);

            res.json(product);
        });
    });
```

**Add To Front-end Angular Controller** - Do this wherever you are doing your http.get for the product

```
   //id is a placeholder for however you are passing in the product id
    $http.get('/api/products/' + id)
        .success(function(data) {
            $scope.product = data;
            console.log(data);
        })
        .error(function(data) {
            console.log('Error: ' + data);
        });
```

Comment: Angular routes don't work. When i go to http://mydomain.com/products/53c92d5dda9cef6c23000002 then it will open index.html with "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < " in every javascript files. This is my github: https://github.com/dakolech/angular-GemStore What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Yeah, it looks like all the requests that aren't resolved in public get the index.html file and that is due to the routes not working. I'd open up a new question on it though.